# Improve terrible annotate() query

Tags: mysql, django

Here is the current query I have that orders an `order_item` by the most recent timestamp.

```
order_items.annotate(newest_note_time=Max('ordernotes__timestamp')).
    order_by('newest_note_time')
```

It works. However, in viewing it in `debug-toolbar` it is giving me two brutal queries, that are all but identical. I have tried doing:

```
order_items = order_items.order_by('-ordernotes__timestamp')
```

But that results in an incorrect query that gives me duplicate results.

Is there a better way to do this query without jumping into raw SQL here?

Here is one of the queries (the second is basically identical, no idea why it generates a second...)

```
SELECT ••• FROM `order_orderitem`
INNER JOIN `order_orderitemstatus` ON (`order_orderitem`.`status_id` = `order_orderitemstatus`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `order_order` ON (`order_orderitem`.`order_id` = `order_order`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `title_title` ON (`order_orderitem`.`title_id` = `title_title`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `home_service` ON (`order_orderitem`.`service_id` = `home_service`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_ordernotes` ON (`order_orderitem`.`id` = `order_ordernotes`.`order_item_id`)
WHERE NOT (`order_orderitemstatus`.`name` IN ('Complete', 'Live', 'Archived'))
GROUP BY
  `order_orderitem`.`id`, `order_orderitem`.`order_id`, `order_orderitem`.`title_id`, `order_orderitem`.`service_id`,
  `order_orderitem`.`metadata_locale_id`, `order_orderitem`.`purchase_order`, `order_orderitem`.`due_date`, `order_orderitem`.`feature`,
  `order_orderitem`.`trailer`, `order_orderitem`.`artwork`, `order_orderitem`.`chaptering`, `order_orderitem`.`cc`,
  `order_orderitem`.`metadata`, `order_orderitem`.`subtitles`, `order_orderitem`.`forced_narrative`, `order_orderitem`.`qc_note`,
  `order_orderitem`.`audio`, `order_orderitem`.`dub_card`, `order_orderitem`.`live_url`, `order_orderitem`.`metadata_valid`,
  `order_orderitem`.`status_id`, `order_orderitem`.`date_created`, `order_order`.`id`, `order_order`.`number`, `order_order`.`provider_id`,
  `order_order`.`date_created`, `order_order`.`date_ordered`, `order_order`.`is_archived`, `title_title`.`id`, `title_title`.`film_id`,
  `title_title`.`name`, `title_title`.`provider_id`, `title_title`.`original_locale_id`, `title_title`.`country_of_origin_id`,
  `title_title`.`synopsis`, `title_title`.`production_company`, `title_title`.`copyright`, `title_title`.`run_time`,
  `title_title`.`original_theatrical_release`, `title_title`.`color`, `title_title`.`film_type`, `title_title`.`no_cc_reason`,
  `title_title`.`includes_hd`, `title_title`.`provider_identifier`, `title_title`.`episode_production_number`, `title_title`.`container_position`,
  `title_title`.`season_id`, `home_service`.`id`, `home_service`.`name`, `home_service`.`notes`, `order_orderitemstatus`.`id`,
  `order_orderitemstatus`.`name`, `order_orderitemstatus`.`department_id`, `order_orderitemstatus`.`is_finished`,
  `order_orderitemstatus`.`ordering` ORDER BY NULL
```

Comment: what the raw sql would look like?

Comment: @DmitryBeransky see updated.

Comment: no, i meant if you were to write this in SQL, what would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
.select_related(depth=1)
```

Add that to the end of your original query and see if any magic happens.

Another possible fix for awful queries that I have is to just cache the page. Add the following to the top of your file:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
```

and then just above your def... add:

```
@cache_page(60 * 5)
```

which is 60 seconds * 5, for 5 minutes. Change the time to whatever is appropriate for you.